# Media keys toolbar on task bar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, toolbar, media-keys

My keyboard does not have media keys. Does anyone know of a toolbar or something for the Windows 7 taskbar which would add the basic keys there? Like a previous, next and pause button or something.

Answer (score 7):

[Taskplay](https://github.com/evilpro/Taskplay/releases) does that for you: it adds play/pause, previous and next icons in you taskbar and is free (open source).

[image]

Note that for seeing these, you'll have to click on the arrow up next to your taskbar and click `Customize...`

[image]

There you can select the icons you want to be displayed permanently (they'll seem invisible because they are white):

[image]

I've tested it with AIMP and Google Play (the web app) and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this depend on your media player? With Spotify, if you hover over the program on the taskbar it displays little icons to play/pause the current song, and to fast forward/rewind the song.

I'm pretty sure Windows Media Player still allows you to put the mini player interface on the toolbar.

Comment: That is true with Spotify yes, but I'm talking about the functionality you get with media keys on your keyboard which works with (pretty much) any music player which is currently open.